# How to create ViewController navigation like Feedly iOS APP?

Tags: ios, user-interface

I want to create interactive view controller transition like feedly ios app.

It uses `Swipe-gesture` to push and pop view controller i.e. you can remove current view controller by `slide-up` gesture and you can see next view controller beneath it while doing so.

Possible option :- Interactive-View-Controller transitions, but you cant see next view controller beneath it this way.

Comment: UIPageViewController does all this for you

Comment: by using UIPageViewController or by adding SwipeGestures you can achieve this functionality.

Comment: I tried it but UIPageViewController just slides view controllers like a roll, what i want is next view controller completely hidden behind current view controller.

Answer (score 0):

This may help you : http://www.iosnomad.com/blog/2014/5/12/interactive-custom-container-view-controller-transitions

I think you can achieve what you want to do with Interactive Transitions.
I didn't try Interactive transition yet, but with custom transition, you can see the next ViewController during the transition.

And the purpose of Custom transitions and Interactive transitions is to have a nice animation between both View Controllers.
So I think you can see the destination View Controller during the animation by using Interactive Transition.

Comment: yup i have already been through this article. It creates interactive transition but doesnt solve the purpose of putting the next view controller behind the current one. And you can see the next viewcontroller while you are sliding the current one. Please see the feedly ios app to see what i mean.